# Disable specific Icon in React for specific Keycloak users

Tags: reactjs, typescript, keycloak

I have a Datatable (which is basically a Materialtable with some presets taken care of) in which certain icons are displayed. Now some of those Icons should only be visible and useable for Keycloak users with certain roles.
Let's say the table looks something like this, and admin users should be able to see all icons, but a customer should not see the "edit" and the "delete" icon.

---

```js
<Grid item>
          <DataTable
            title={'TableTitle'}
            columns={tableColumns}
            data={product.information ? product.information : []}
            headerStyle={headerStyle}
            actions={[
              {
                icon: 'email',
                tooltip: t('send-email'),
                onClick: (event: any, rowData: Information) => {
                  onSendEmail(rowData)
                },
              },
              {
                icon: 'edit',
                onClick: () => {
                  handleOpen()
                  // TODO: Edit row item
                },
              },
              {
                icon: 'delete',
                onClick: () => {
                  handleClick()
                  // TODO: remove the item
                },
              },
              {
                icon: 'add',
                isFreeAction: true,
                onClick: () => {
                  handleOpen()
                },
              },
            ]}
          ></DataTable>
          <AddInformationDialog
            id="addInformationDialog"
            keepMounted
            handleClose={handleClose}
            onAddInformation={onAddInformation}
            open={open}
          ></AddInformationDialog>
          <ConfirmationDialog
            id="deleteDialog"
            keepMounted
            open={openDelete}
            onClose={handleCloseDelete}
            value={value}
          ></ConfirmationDialog>
        </Grid>
```

I haven't tried anything because I am pretty new to React, Typescript, and Keycloak so I have no idea which options I have.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the elements depending if its Keygroup or not:

```js
function restrictAccess(arr) {
  return arr.map(
    item =>  item.icon === "edit" || item.icon === "add" ? null : item
  ).filter(item => item !== null);
};
```

Comment: I added this function to the KeycloakEventHandler.tsx but when I call it in general, not even for a specific role nothing happens.

Comment: @luk139 it is just an example how you can deal with it. :) I dont know your structure but if you go with an MVVM, then you should handle it there. An "enventhanlder" sounds more like repo stuff.

Comment: thank you. I'll see if I find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
  actions={[
          {
            icon: 'email',
            tooltip: t('send-email'),
            onClick: (event: any, rowData: Information) => {
              onSendEmail(rowData)
            },
          },
          {
            icon: 'edit',
            onClick: () => {
              handleOpen()
              // TODO: Edit row item
            },
            hidden: keycloak.hasRealmRole('RestrictedRole'), 
          }
        ]}
```

apparently MaterialTable has a "hidden" feature, which fixed this easier than expected.